# symfony 4 fixtures datetime method not working with string from PDO data always set "now"

Tags: symfony, datetime, pdo, fixtures

I try to migrate some data from WordPress to my Symfony application using Symfony Doctrine Fixtures.

Everything is working beside migrating date from wordpress mysql database column 'post_date'.

For example my variable from mysql looks like this: $post_value['post_date'] = '2018-03-30 21:05:24';
and was taken by using PDO. This string is real and I just copied/pasted it here ;)

then i've got in DataFixtures something like this:

```
$item = new Articles();
$item->setDateCreated(new \DateTime($post_value['post_date']));
...
$this->manager->persist($item);
...
$this->manager->flush();
```

in database it does not put migrated values, but a current datetime similar to using \DateTime("now")

my results from mysql are (new/another database.table.column):

```
SELECT distinct(date_created) FROM articles;

'2019-12-12 22:37:01'
'2019-12-12 22:37:02'
'2019-12-12 22:37:03'
'2019-12-12 22:37:04'
'2019-12-12 22:37:05'
'2019-12-12 22:37:06'
```

**EDIT:**

those a couple results from sql distinct follows from migrating all data and example above concerned one entry

**EDIT2:**

```
//hard print_r for fisrt row

echo "\n ---- \n >>>";
print_r($post_value['post_date']);
echo "<<< \n ---- \n ";
die();

//result with this
 ----
 >>>2010-05-25 23:05:20<<<
 ----
```

so the value is not empty

Comment: What do you get if you add the statement `dd($post_value['post_date']);` immediately before the statement that begins `$item->setDateCreated`? The behavior suggests that `$post_value['post_date']` is empty.

Comment: echo "\n ---- \n >>>";
print_r($post_value['post_date']);
echo "<<< \n ---- \n ";
die();  ----
 >>>2010-05-25 23:05:20<<<
 ----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not from this code, but more from the entity.

Two possibilities :

1. The entity, when is saved, override the datetime value.
2. The column is configured to automaticaly add the "NOW()" function instead of the value of the variable.

Then, to know exactly whats happening, you can use some of those clues :

1. Check if your entity use a Doctrine Lifecycle. If so, check that this datetime value is not overrided during the @Prepersist method.
2. The column should be annoted only by : `@Column(type="datetime")`.
3. Check if you don't use any Doctrine Timestampable bundle/traits in your entity.

Comment: Thank You for response, i had got in prePersist method (EventListener) setter $entity->setDateCreated(new \DateTime("now")); . Solution was checking if delivered date value is instanceof of DateTime class, if not just use DateTime with "now"